# "annotation value must be an annotation " - for @Builder Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, java-11, lombok

I am trying to use the `@Builder` annotation on my class and I get this compilation error:

`**error: annotation value must be an annotation**`

```
C:\Sample\Work\SpringBoot-Version\SpringBoot-3.0\spring-base-dependencies\spring-base-api\src\main\java\com\sample\cloudnative\base\api\BaseBodyError.java:19: error: annotation value must be an annotation @Builder ^** 1 error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. 
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. 

* Try: 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I am using Lombok 1.18.24, Spring Boot 3.0.2, and Java 17.

This was an Exiting Code working for Java version 11 with spring Boot 2.7 . I just updated the Java Version to 17 and updated the Boot Version to 3.0.2 and just ran gradlew clean build. I am getting this error .

The Java class  I am  compiling

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.ford.cloudnative.base.api.annotation.ApiProperty;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.*;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map; 
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ApiModel(description = "Base Body Error")
public class BaseBodyError {

    @Singular
    @Size(max = 8192)
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "List of data errors")
    List<@NotNull BaseBodyDataError> dataErrors;

    @Singular
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Error field attributes")
    Map<String, Object> attributes;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @ApiModel(description = "Base Body Data Error")
    public static class BaseBodyDataError {

        @Size(max = 1024, message = "code length is limited to 1024 characters")
        @Pattern(regexp = "^.{0,1024}$")
        @ApiModelProperty(example = "Unauthorized", value = "Error Code")
        String code;

      
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Can you show the complete error (as text)? `@Builder` on its own is just fine.

Comment: You'll need to include a minimal, reproducible example and explain how you're compiling it.

Comment: This was an Exiting Code working for Java version 11 with spring Boot 2.7 . I just updated the Java Version to 17 and updated the Boot Version to  3.0.2  and just ran gradlew clean build. I am  getting this error .

Comment: And the imports, and kindly limit the example to the smallest code that exhibits the problem.